# How to press the windows key with pynput?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

I am making a program in which I want to use Windows + D combination to navigate to desktop, but I am unable to find a windows key in `Key.<Keyname>` to do that. How can I do that? If not, is there any other way i should do this instead?

Comment: Which OS do you want Windows + D to work on? I'm aware of that working on Linux Ubuntu for instance. Do other OSs support this key sequence to show the desktop too?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure this out. I asked a new question: [pynput library not working as expected in Python to press Windows + D key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76399361/4561887)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try cmd, cmd_l and cmd_r as seen in the [pynput documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html#pynput.keyboard.Key.cmd).

Answer (score 1):

```
import keyboard
keyboard.press_and_release('windows+d')
```

To install:

`pip install keyboard`
I dont know how to use pynput and use the keyboard library, sorry

Comment: `raise ImportError('You must be root to use this library on linux.')`. That stinks you have to be root to use this library. And then when I try to import it as root, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard'`. So...no luck so far.

Comment: And if I do `sudo pip install keyboard` instead of just `pip install keyboard`, to try to give root access to this library, then run my file with `sudo python3 my_test_file.py`, it still doesn't work. Now I get `IndexError: tuple index out of range` on the `keyboard.press_and_release('windows+d')` line. So, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

the Keyname for the Windows Button is cmd_l.

if you want to press it just use it as:  variable.press(Key.cmd_l)

Answer (score 0):

From my answer here: [pynput library not working as expected in Python to press Windows + D key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76544123/4561887):

This presses <kbd>Windows</kbd> (<kbd>Super</kbd>) + <kbd>D</kbd>:

```py
import time

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller


# ========== technique 1 ===========
# From: https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html
print("Trying technique 1")

keyboard = Controller()
SUPER_KEY = Key.cmd
with keyboard.pressed(SUPER_KEY):
    keyboard.press('d')
    keyboard.release('d')


time.sleep(1.0)


# ========== technique 2 ===========
print("Trying technique 2")

keyboard = Controller()
SUPER_KEY = Key.cmd

keyboard.press(SUPER_KEY)
keyboard.press('d')
keyboard.release('d')
keyboard.release(SUPER_KEY)
```

Due to a bug in `pynput`, this won't work in Linux though (ex: Ubuntu 22.04). See my answer in the link above for details, and instructions on using `ydotool` instead.