# pynput library not working as expected in Python to press Windows + D key

Tags: python, linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events, pynput

I'm trying to do what this question asked (this question has no valid answers with functional code using `pynput`): [Press Windows+D with `pynput`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63489008/4561887). But, my attempts are not working as expected.

On Linux Ubuntu, pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> will minimize all windows, thereby showing the desktop. Doing it again will bring all the windows back as they were.

Here's my code:

```py
import time

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()
SUPER_KEY = Key.cmd

keyboard.press(SUPER_KEY)
# time.sleep(1)
keyboard.press('d')
keyboard.release('d')
keyboard.release(SUPER_KEY)
```

When I run it, I expect the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> shortcut to be pressed, hiding all windows. Instead, only the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key is pressed, which brings up the program launcher search tool, and then a single `d` is left printed in my terminal, like this:

```bash
$ ./pynput_press_Windows+D_to_show_the_desktop.py 
$ d
```

How do I get this to work?

The reference documentation says (https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) that `Key.cmd` is the "Super" or "Windows" key. I've also tried with `Key.cmd_l` and `Key.cmd_r`.

> `cmd` = 0
>
> A generic command button. On PC platforms, this corresponds to the Super key or Windows key, and on Mac it corresponds to the Command key. This may be a modifier.
>
> `cmd_l` = 0
>
> The left command button. On PC platforms, this corresponds to the Super key or Windows key, and on Mac it corresponds to the Command key. This may be a modifier.
>
> `cmd_r` = 0
>
> The right command button. On PC platforms, this corresponds to the Super key or Windows key, and on Mac it corresponds to the Command key. This may be a modifier.

---

Update 4 June 2023: keyboard monitor test program, to ensure `Key.cmd` + `d` is correct for my keyboard (it is): modified from https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard:

```py
from pynput import keyboard

print("Keyboard monitor demo program. Press Esc to exit.")

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(
            key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(
            key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(
        key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        print("Exiting the program.")
        return False

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Sample output when I press Super + D:

```bash
$ ./pynput_monitor_keyboard.py 
Keyboard monitor demo program. Press Esc to exit.
Key.enter released
special key Key.cmd pressed
alphanumeric key d pressed
'd' released
Key.cmd released
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to tie the loose ends on this question.

As far as I can tell, my code in the question is fine. [@Сергей Кох's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76400057/4561887) is fine too. **There is just a bug in `pynput` is all, preventing it from working in Ubuntu.** <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> fails, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> fails, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> fails.

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.2, and even in the X11 window manager (as opposed to Wayland), it still doesn't work.

Here's my bug report: [Bug on Linux: Windows (Super) + D doesn't work](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/556)

Here is some valid code that *should* work. If you have a Mac or Windows, please try it out and leave a comment if this code works or not. Both techniques here should be equally valid. Note: a list of all possible keys is here: https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#pynput.keyboard.Key

```py
import time

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller


# ========== technique 1 ===========
# From: https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html
print("Trying technique 1")

keyboard = Controller()
SUPER_KEY = Key.cmd
with keyboard.pressed(SUPER_KEY):
    keyboard.press('d')
    keyboard.release('d')


time.sleep(1.0)


# ========== technique 2 ===========
print("Trying technique 2")

keyboard = Controller()
SUPER_KEY = Key.cmd

keyboard.press(SUPER_KEY)
keyboard.press('d')
keyboard.release('d')
keyboard.release(SUPER_KEY)
```

The [suggestion was made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76399361/pynput-library-not-working-as-expected-in-python-to-press-windows-d-key/76544123?noredirect=1#comment134961373_76544123) to try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. It makes no difference, and also doesn't work due to whatever bug is going on. Here is my test code. Note: I also tried `Key.ctrl_l` instead of `Key.ctrl`, and it made no difference.

```py
import time

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller


# ========== technique 1 ===========
# From: https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html
print("Trying technique 1")

keyboard = Controller()
SUPER_KEY = Key.cmd

with keyboard.pressed(Key.ctrl):
    with keyboard.pressed(SUPER_KEY):
        keyboard.press('d')
        keyboard.release('d')


time.sleep(1.0)


# ========== technique 2 ===========
print("Trying technique 2")

keyboard = Controller()
SUPER_KEY = Key.cmd

keyboard.press(Key.ctrl)
keyboard.press(SUPER_KEY)
keyboard.press('d')
keyboard.release('d')
keyboard.release(SUPER_KEY)
keyboard.release(Key.ctrl)
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> also works manually, same as the options above, but *not* with `pynput`. This code also fails to have any effect. Note that I also tried `Key.alt_gr` and `Key.alt_l` in place of `Key.alt` in the code below, and both of those failed too:

```py
import time

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller


# ========== technique 1 ===========
# From: https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html
print("Trying technique 1")

keyboard = Controller()

with keyboard.pressed(Key.ctrl):
    with keyboard.pressed(Key.alt):
        keyboard.press('d')
        keyboard.release('d')


time.sleep(1.0)


# ========== technique 2 ===========
print("Trying technique 2")

keyboard = Controller()

keyboard.press(Key.ctrl)
keyboard.press(Key.alt)
keyboard.press('d')
keyboard.release('d')
keyboard.release(Key.alt)
keyboard.release(Key.ctrl)
```

So, for people on Ubuntu, if you want to automate a tool to press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, use [`wmctrl`](https://askubuntu.com/a/905480/327339) or `ydotool` instead:

1. I have posted a full demo in my answer here: [Ask Ubuntu: How can I write a program to press keys, such as Windows + D, in Wayland? (replace `xdotool` in Wayland)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1473061/327339), and
2. I have written a full article with even more info on my website here: [Tutorial: Getting started with ydotool to automate key presses (or mouse movements) in Linux](https://gabrielstaples.com/ydotool-tutorial/).

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+Super+D, Ctrl + Alt + D ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/27775/how-do-i-minimize-all-the-windows-using-a-keyboard-shortcut

Comment: @СергейКох, no luck. It made no difference. I updated my answer. On my computer, both Ctrl + Super + D and just Super + D by itself work if I press them manually on my keyboard.

Comment: Trying Ctrl + Alt + D now. It works manually, let's see if pynput can do it.

Comment: @СергейКох, nope: `pynput` fails with those options too. I updated the answer again.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dual language keyboard, a different keyboard "shortcut" may work. On my Russian-English keyboard, pressing the Russian "в" worked, which is "d" in the English layout. I learned this using keyboard monitoring from the [documentation](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard) by pressing "win + d" on the keyboard.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

with keyboard.pressed(Key.cmd):
    keyboard.press('в')
    keyboard.release('в')
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try out the keyboard monitoring. I'm on a regular US English keyboard. What OS are you on?

Comment: I ran the test. For me, it is indeed `Key.cmd`, and `d`. I'll add the output to my question.

Comment: Done. My question is updated. And I ran you code with the modification of using `d` instead of `в`, and it still doesn't work for me. The `Key.cmd` works right, but the `d` gets sent to the terminal instead of as a key joined to `Key.cmd` to show the desktop.

Comment: @GabrielStaples   I have windows 10, python 3.11, pycharm. I have tried before this the following libraries pyautogui, keyboard - they don't work on this keyboard shortcut. Only win32api worked right away. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65664978/simulate-wind-show-desktop-from-python-script.

Comment: I think your code is correct, and that the fact it doesn't work on my Linux computer is a bug. I've opened a bug report with `pynput`: https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/556

Comment: Upvoted for being useful, but I have written [my own answer here too.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76544123/4561887) I'm concluding it's just a pynput bug.